# JavaScript oninput validation 1 at a time

Tags: javascript

I have 2 input fields, Length and Width. I am using real time validation and calculations with no submit button. I am stuck on 1 issue, when I input length "len" it immediately validates the width as well. or if I input width first it validated len too. I want them to validate only when that particular field is inputted.

For both the len and width input text fields I have oninput="Validate()" in the HTML. So oninput for len is automatically checking the validation for width before the user even attempts to input width.

Anyway to break or stop after just 1 of the validations fail so they aren't both always being validated? Or do I need to use 2 separate functions for oninput?

When both validations pass I then need to pass variables on to Calculate(len, width); for the final calculations and display.

```
function Validate()
{
    // user input
    var len = parseFloat(document.getElementById("len").value); 
    var width = parseFloat(document.getElementById("width").value);

    var lenValid;
    var widthValid;

    // validate
    if (isNaN(len) || len <= 0 || len > 1000)
    {
        document.getElementById("len_error").innerHTML = "<br>" + "Must be between 0 and 1000";
        document.getElementById("len").focus();
        lenValid = false;
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("len_error").innerHTML = "";
        lenValid = true;
    }

    if (isNaN(width) || width <= 0 || width > 1000)
    {
        document.getElementById("width_error").innerHTML = "<br>" + "Must be between 0 and 1000";
        document.getElementById("width").focus();
        widthValid = false;
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("width_error").innerHTML = "";
        widthValid = true;
    }

    // process calculations
    if (lenValid && widthValid)
        Calculate(len, width);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can optimize the code in the following way.

```
function Validate(lw)
{
    // user input
    var len = parseFloat(document.getElementById("len").value); 
    var width = parseFloat(document.getElementById("width").value);

    // validate
    if (len <= 0 || len > 1000 || isNaN(len))
        document.getElementById("len_error").innerHTML = "<br>" + "Must be between 0 and 1000";
    else
        document.getElementById("len_error").innerHTML = "";
    if (width <= 0 || width > 1000 || isNaN(width))
        document.getElementById("width_error").innerHTML = "<br>" + "Must be between 0 and 1000";
    else
        document.getElementById("width_error").innerHTML = "";

    if (document.getElementById("len_error").innerHTML || document.getElementById("width_error").innerHTML)
    {
        document.getElementById("area").value = "";
        document.getElementById("perimeter").value = "";
        document.getElementById("diagonal").value = "";
        document.getElementById(lw).focus();
    }
    else
        Calculate(len, width);
}
```

Comment: That does not seem to be correct. Putting !isNaN(len) shows the validation error message when I input numbers, and it allows letters to pass validation. Changing my last statement to your suggestion also did not help.

Comment: why would I do that? putting !isNaN(len) only allows letters to pass validation. You use numbers not letters to calculate Area (length * width).

Comment: Your updated version is as little closer but still has issues. If I input 1 digit for len, like a 2 for example, it immediately jumps to validate the width without letting me input anymore numbers, like if I wanted 2 to be 21, or 210. It still seems to be validating width right along with len.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125260/discussion-between-karpak-and-programmer7).

Comment: Your latest edit still does the same thing the previous ones did. Looks like I will just have to use a submit button for this, it is not going to work with real time calculation